# Overload jQuery constructor to use own object

Tags: jquery, constructor, typescript, overloading

I'm pretty new to `TypeScript` and not sure if this is possible.
My application uses `jQuery`. To create a new `JQuery` I can use:

```
var $someElement = $("#someString");
```

I have an object defined which looks something like this:

```
class HtmlElementId {
    private idPrefix: string = "#";

    id: string;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;

        if (id.indexOf(this.idPrefix) !== 0) {
            this.id = this.idPrefix + id;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to somehow overload the JQuery constructor to make something like this

```
$(idElement : HtmlElementId){
    return $(idElement.id);
}
```

So I can use it in code like

```
var myIdElement = new HtmlIdElement("someString");

var $someElement = $(myIdElement); // <- this is what I want
```

Question: Is this possible? And, if so, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you just want to extend the type definition (assuming you are using something like DefinitelyTyped/tsd) or do you want to know how to write the code to override jQuery?

Comment: @billc.cn I do use DefinitelyTyped and don't want to change the *.d.ts files. Can it be extended inside a single file interface definition?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think something like this might work

```
var $ = (id: string) => {
    return new HtmlIdElement(id);
}

$("test")
```

Although I do have a feeling that now when using jQuery you might need to us jQuery("") instead of $("") since you have replace $ with your own definition

Comment: And where should I put this in order to have it available in a `global` scope all over my `TypeScript` classes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the `JQueryStatic` interface using [Declaration Merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#declaration-merging).

In your case, the code is simple:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    (idElement: HtmlElementId): JQuery;
}
```

You can add this to every `.ts` file that uses jQuery this way or to its owd `d.ts` file.

In the latter case, you can replace all references to `jquery.d.ts` with your own file and the compiler will transitively search the `d.ts` files.

Comment: But where and how would I implement the method? Or is it like something to be added to the prototype of `jQuery`?